# waitbar in progress indication - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using inside a Matlab GUI a waitbar and as the only calculation takes long I see the waitbar on the screen presenting the message "Operation is underway". Is there a way to put a clock or a simple spinning icon to indicate that work is in progress (It is not inside a loop so I can use steps)?

Script:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Operation is underway'); 

% Calculations

close(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in the *Calculations* part you are calling a function instead of having a for loop like what [Matlab documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html?searchHighlight=waitbar&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433339/get-waitbar-value-in-matlab) suggest.

```
%% With for loop, no icon
h = waitbar(0,'Starting...');
for i=1:1000,
    pause(0.01);
    relativeValue = i/1000;
    waitbar(relativeValue, h, sprintf('%12.0f %%',relativeValue*100))
end
```

From [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/animated-busy-spinning-icon):

```
%% Undocumented Matlab
% Link: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/animated-busy-spinning-icon
% R2010a and newer
% NOTE: Create your own class which integrates this into a custom Java dialog box

iconsClassName = 'com.mathworks.widgets.BusyAffordance$AffordanceSize';
iconsSizeEnums = javaMethod('values',iconsClassName);
SIZE_32x32 = iconsSizeEnums(2);  % (1) = 16x16,  (2) = 32x32
jObj = com.mathworks.widgets.BusyAffordance(SIZE_32x32, 'testing...');  % icon, label

jObj.setPaintsWhenStopped(true);  % default = false
jObj.useWhiteDots(false);         % default = false (true is good for dark backgrounds)
javacomponent(jObj.getComponent, [10,10,80,80], gcf);
jObj.start;
for i=1:1000,
    pause(0.01); % Just wasting time
end
jObj.stop;
jObj.setBusyText('All done!');
```

This involves building your own Matlab class which creates your own custom dialog which exposes the *start, stop* and other options. If you don't want to go through the trouble, you can use pre-existing libraries built by others, such as [this multiWaitbar](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26589-multiwaitbar--label--varargin--).